# How to set mariadb on jhipster

Tags: maven, mariadb, jhipster, yeoman-generator

I need use MariaDB and I want to start a project with JHipster.

How Can I configure to use MariaDB DataBase?

I try to configure application-prod.yml and pom.xml files but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: "it doesn't work for me" is not enough, please provide details, logs, ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's worked for me:
 1. Configure JHipster to use MySql.
 2. Make sure mariadb is running (depends on you platform, on linux i verified by running the mysql command and making sure it can connect to my db)
 3. Create a database named like your app (i think that should happen somewhere in the generate/build process but for me it didn't, so i created it with 'CREATE DATABASE myappname' from the same mysql command line tool.
 4. Build and run your app with 'mvn' or 'gradle' in the apps root directory.